# Vuejs How to change the URL in a component without quitting this component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm new to VueJs.

I'm working with wizaplace. Actually I have a route called /breweries/:id which takes the id of the wizaplace company (the API takes only an ID to get the company) to call the wizaplace API and get the company informations.

In these data, I have a slug that I would like to display instead of ID in the url.

How could I achieve this please ?

Should I do a "bridge" component, getting company's data by its id and pushing id and slug to another end component that would get another time the company with its ID but displaying $route.params.slug in the URL ?

I know this is not a proper way of working but this is a need in my startup.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some `:name_slug` instead of `:id` you have to resolve this place by this `slug` instad of `id`, so API should be extended/chnaged.
OR if there is fixed amount of places, and you know all of them, just write some function that translate `slug` to `id`

```js
function getIdBySlug(slug){
    //as Json
  const slugsMap = [
    {'i' : 1, 's': 'slug1' },
    {'i' : 2, 's': 'foo' },
    {'i' : 5, 's': 'bar' },
    {'i' : 8, 's': 'kek' }
  ]
  
  const toFind =  slugsMap.find(e=> e.s === slug)
  return toFind ? toFind.i : false
}
// usage
const ID = getIdBySlug('bar');
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/19kxnuLy/